# Convert Eregi_replace to preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need help converting eregi_replace to preg_replace (since in PHP5 it's depreciated):

```
  function makeClickableLinks($text)
  {
  $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                        '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
  $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                        '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
  $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})',
                        '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
  return $text;
  }
```

(It turns text links and emails into hyperlinks so that the user can click on them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with a look at the [list of differences](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) between POSIX and PCRE expressions in the manual.

If your expressions aren't complicated, generally it means that you can get away with simply putting delimiters around your `$pattern` parameter, and switch to use the `preg` family of functions.  In your case, you would do this:

```
 function makeClickableLinks($text)
 {
 $text = preg_replace('/(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
                       '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
 $text = preg_replace('/([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i',
                       '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
 $text = preg_replace('/([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})/i',
                       '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
 return $text;
 }
```

Note the `/` characters around your patterns, and the `i` flag after the delimiters.  I tested this quickly, and it worked for a basic URL.  You'll probably want to test it more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll be looking into the link you have posted and will use your advice to convert other eregi_replace to preg_replace.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Both for the conversion of the function (which is commonly used) and for the pointer to that link. I was looking through the php manual but didn't come across that page.